# axios get run constantly when call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify

I create app.get to return token from Spotify

here is the code :

```
 axios({
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "Basic " +
        Buffer.from(clientId + ":" + clientSecret).toString("base64"),
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    params: {
      grant_type: "refresh_token",
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      res.json({
        accessToken: response.data.access_token,
        expiresIn: response.data.expires_in,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.statusCode));
});
```

and a function on the client-side whenever I call, it will return the token but when I console log the code below, it prints out non-stop

here the code:

```
let getData = () => {
    axios.request("http://localhost:3001/refresh_token").then((response) => {
      SetToken(response.data);
      setExpires(response.data.expiresIn);
      console.log(token);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = setInterval(() => {
      getData();
    }, 1000);
  });

  return (
    <div className="spotify">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          getData();
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is missing a dependency array, so it will be called for every rerender of your component (and even worse, it will create a new interval timeout that's never cleared every time). I'll bravely assume `setToken` and `setExpires` are state setters for the component, so those would cause rerenders.

You'll need

```
useEffect(() => {
  const dataTimer = setInterval(() => {
    getData();
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(dataTimer);
}, []); // <- this empty dependency array
```

so it will only be called once when your component mounts, and so the interval is cleaned up when it unmounts.

(`getData` should also be in that dependency array, but since you're not seemingly memoizing it using `useCallback`, that would negate the benefit of the empty array, since the identity of `getData` would also be changing on each render...)

Comment: thank you for replying, I want to call the getData(); to get the token when the page is load and then after that the interval kick in but when I code it like this   `useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    const data = setInterval(() => {
      getData();
    }, (expiresIn - 60) * 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(data);
  }, [getData]);` and i get back to the same error